# A new project with the same SHA1

Tags: android-studio, firebase, sha1

So, I've been practicing with Firebase recently and did a project, it works fine. Today I've decided to move on and create another project and here comes the problem:

The SHA1 of my new project appears to be the same with SHA1 of my previous project. I don't know why this happens, but it is pretty strange.

What can be done? I need the SHA1 since in Firebase I'm using the Auth in both projects and it requires me to enter another SHA1 for my second project.

EDIT: I've also checked my previous old projects and they appear to have this SAME SHA1 fingerprint. I was okay with that until now, since Firebase won't let me create a new project with the same SHA1, so I basically need a way to change SHA1 on my latest project. Any ideas?

Comment: if i recall you can add a sha1 fingerprint in project setting yourself

Comment: @MasihAkbari could you tell me how to do it, or where to read on how to do it. I've searched, but couldn't find anything yet.

Comment: Great to hear that you found a solution. Please add that solution as an answer. Stack Overflow is different from other forums in that questions and answers have a different status/meaning. Adding your own answer and marking it as accepted is the proper way to handle this.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you for your guide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution, it's just that I had tried to add this second app initially to the Firebase under an old project, so to solve this issue I just deleted the duplicate app from another project that I've created in Firebase and no more errors occurred.